# Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.10, Gradle 3.x is not supported yet

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

*Full Title I wanted*:

> Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.10, Gradle 3.x is not supported yet. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in ...\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

I have an old project that I am trying to open in Android Studio 2.2 (Preview 6) and when I try to build the project, I get the following error.

> Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.10, Gradle 3.x is not supported yet. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\home\Documents\code\MY_PROJECTS\notify-me-not-app\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

[image]

I did go to the `gradle-wrapper.properties` below and this is what my file looks like:

> \gradle\wrapper

```
#Fri Jul 17 23:20:07 CDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Comment: what does your build.gradle file say in terms of gradle version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using 2.4 which is less than 2.10 (4 < 10). Change the distribution URL like it asks to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: I was assume 2.10, means it's 2.1 so < 2.4, This helped.