# Failed to sync gradle 3.1 project in Android Studio:

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I'm new to Android Studio. When I open it I keep getting an error that says "Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter'."

I'm using Android 2.2 and gradle 3.1

[image]

[image]

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your error from Gradle Console" tab.? so i can give you proper solutions.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not getting this [same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38557177/2745495) error?

I don't think you can use Gradle 3.x for Android Studio.
From this this [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility), maybe the supported right now is up to 2.x.
Try downgrading the Gradle version.

Comment: I'm not sure understand that the plus means "or higher". It might not be documented to use version 3, but it claims that it can be used

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I understand that "+" means it could also include 3.x. Edited answer to clarify that maybe only 2.x is supported. Thanks.